# Is there a TCP Socket Library/Protocol that does message framing and is supported in JS & C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm in the process of building an application that requires clients to exchange messages between each other (similar to chat) using a server.

I want to write the server in JavaScript using Node JS, the client applications are written in C#.NET.

I've researched for a while and discarded Socket.IO due to the lack of C# support and because I'm looking for something more low-level and flexible/customizable.

I'm written once an application very similar which used the built in NodeJS 'net' module as the server and the C# TCPClient client-side, it works, but it uses a stream and I have to prefix the message length before each message.

I'm looking for something more redundant that has message framing out-of-the-box and is supported by the languages I'm using.

I've found the 'ws' (WebSocket) npm module which seems like a promising candidate, especially since it might go along well with the C# Socket class (which is also the underlying socket used by the TCPistener and TCPClient classes) but for the life of me I can't figure out if I'll still have to expect a Socket Stream or just set an event handler for new message events.

I'm looking for something that's really simple to implement and will notify for each message I receive so I can handle it, no matter the size of the message or buffer (I plan to send average messages a megabyte in size...), I never want to handle the buffer, and of course it should be well supported in the above languages.

Comment: WebSockets works with messages, you don't need to prefix the size, You will just hook to the Message event and it will be received complete.

Comment: @Gusman so server-side I use 'ws'? what is the name of the package/class to use client-side (using c#)?

Comment: I use websocket-sharp because it's portable and works perfectly with mono/linux but if your target is just Windows then you can use the integrated websockets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gusman Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets already work with messages, you don't need to prefix the size, just hook to the message event and it will be received complete.

I personally use websocket-sharp because it's portable and works perfectly under mono/linux, but if your target is just Windows yo can use the integrated .net websockets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My final implementation will be streaming images with messages up to 1MB, I've had issues when using a stream protocol where message only partly arrived in the buffer and I had to wait until the full message arrived, I could only wait If I knew how many bytes were missing, To know that I needed the message length before hand.

Comment: If you say that no matter the size using WebSockets will make sure the message arrives in full, then I have no issue with it, I've also read online that WebSockets does it's own message framing to ensure that.

Comment: Yes, internally WebSockets uses it's own framing control, so it's ensured if a message arrives it will be complete.